# Python Graphviz Editor or GUI Framework

Tags: python, graph, wxpython, graphviz, dot

I have written a python application which generates output in graphviz DOT format. I convert the generated file into PNG using the external 'dot' utility and open the generated PNG in an image viewer to visualise the graph.

My application is an interactive command-line tool which allows few operations on the graph like changing the colours of edges based on the edge weights, deleting few nodes, etc. After these operations I generate the DOT file again and convert it to PNG for visualisation.

I came across [xdot.py](https://github.com/jrfonseca/xdot.py) which allows me to embed the interactive viewer into my application. Now I do not have to go to the shell to generate the PNG every time.

I want to take this idea further and build a full-fledged GUI application on top of this. I have few questions regarding this:

- Do I have to start from scratch (use wxPython or any other GUI framework)? Use a canvas to display the generated image and refresh it whenever there are operations performed on the graph.
- Is there any other package which serves this purpose? I am looking for some package which can edit the graph and just provide me with the ability to bind my graph operations to the mouse events on the viewer.

Any other ideas? Greatly appreciate your inputs.

Answer (score 0):

wxPython can display images very easily using wx.StaticBitmap. Here's a tutorial on the subject:

- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/03/26/creating-a-simple-photo-viewer-with-wxpython/

You will probably need to do something like this:

```
img = wx.Image(filepath, wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY)
self.imageCtrl = wx.StaticBitmap(self.panel, wx.ID_ANY, 
                                 wx.BitmapFromImage(img))
```

Then just refresh it whenever you update the image. Depending on your graphing needs, there is the matplotlib project which can be integrated into wxPython.

There is a project that use wxPython and pydot that you might find useful: http://code.google.com/p/pyflowuca/. I saw it mentioned here: http://pythonhaven.wordpress.com/2009/12/09/generating_graphs_with_pydot/